# "some_variable = []" type of statement in matlab

Tags: matlab

Hello and thanks for the help,

I have seen that you can make this statement:

```
some_variable = []
```

from what I see, this makes like a void variable for later use.

The thing is I want to make it an array (and that is the problem). I made this

```
some_variable(:) = []
```

but there is an error:

> In an assignment  A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same

Thanks

Comment: some_variable = [] tell's matlab that some_variable can be an array of any dimension - I don't see what your problem is.

Comment: `[]` creates an array of the **default datatype** (`double` for most of us, unless you [INSIST](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/155369)). `someVar = []` is used as a "placeholder" for the variable name, which suggests that something will be assigned into it later...

Comment: If you just want an array then use `some_variable = zeros(n,1)` . It will give you an  array of length `n` and type `double`. `some_variable = []` is just like declaring an array with no size.

Comment: You should probably try to explain why you need this. There may be a working solution for your problem.

Comment: or maybe you can use a [struct](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html) array

Comment: Do you know the eventual dimensions of the variable when you start adding to it? (I assume you're going to grow this array in some way.)

Answer (score 2):

Actually everything in MATLAB is an array, sometimes the arrays are just 1x1, but they are arrays nevertheless (unlike in C/C++ where you have `int` or `int*`).

So, when you do `var=[]` you initialize an **empty array**, an array of size 0*.

After that, its up to you to initialize it with whatever size you want. `var=0` will initialize it as an array of 1x1 size, but you can go bigger, using `zeros(size)`.

Adittionally, if you want to create empty variables of another class, just use `<classname>.empty`, such as in `var=uint32.empty;`

*Note that in MATLAB, an array is also infinite dimensional. It's not size 0, its 0x0x0x0x0x.....x0x0. If you want to prove this, try `size(var,999999999999)` in MATLAB.

Comment: Then, if I understand, does not have sense to define `someVariable(:)=[]` because actually the someVariable is an array to be define. Later on I will have to define it like an array of any dimensions I want

Comment: @hodei_cloud Exactly. If you want it empty, then empty, else, fill an specific size you define.

Comment: @hodei_cloud Is there anything else I can help you with? Else, please, if the answer helped you, coudl you please accept the answer as valid, so future people can know this is the rigth answer?